# ASMX WebService is not getting request values from xmlns:ns1 sub namespaces (xmlns:ns1 issue)

Tags: web-services

I have .NET 4.6 ASMX WebService generated with the use of WSDL.exe utility from provided WSDL.xml file.

### After start it shows correct (as I understood) sample of usage:

```
POST /LSS3.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <StoreBalanceRequest xmlns="urn:sibur:po:a:store:Balance">
      <Plant>string</Plant>
      <Material>string</Material>
      <PartyNumber>string</PartyNumber>
    </StoreBalanceRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
---------------------
```

But when I test it with Google Postman by Customer provided Request text (He assumes that this text MUST work in this Service and no other ways...)

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns1:StoreBalanceRequest xmlns:ns1="urn:sibur:po:a:store:Balance">
      <Plant>string</Plant>
      <Material>string</Material>
      <PartyNumber>string</PartyNumber>
    </ns1:StoreBalanceRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

WebService never works, it crashes with the following error:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was not available to process request. ---&gt; System.NullReferenceException: Object link is empty or doesnt point to an object.
   в SiburSevice.ExternalStockRequest_In_SyncBinding.ExternalStockRequest_In_Sync(StoreBalanceRequest StoreBalanceRequest)
   --- End of Trace ---</faultstring>
            <detail />
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

Could not undestand why theese things  xmlns:ns1 are not seen in XML request...

Please help!